# Strange determinant result

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, homework

I carried out the determinant of a $4\times4$ matrix in two different ways: with Laplace and without Laplace (see [this attachment](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=90143443555156237733) please).

The Laplace's rule is applied "manually" in *Mathematica* (I carried out the 4 determinants of the 4 matrices $3\times3$; I deleted the second row of the $4\times4$ matrix).

The correct result is $k_{12}/v^3$.

```
WolframAlpha["determinant of \
{{0,1/v,0,-k12/v^2},{0,0,0,-1/v^2},{k12,k01,0,0},{1,1,1,0}}", 
 PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

When I sum the 4 determinants, I get $-k_{12}/v$. Why?

```
WolframAlpha["determinant of \
{{1/v,0,-k_{12}/v^2},{k_{01},0,0},{1,1,0}}", 
 PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution"}]

WolframAlpha["determinant of \
{{0,0,-k_{12}/v^2},{k_{12},0,0},{1,1,0}}", 
 PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution"}]

WolframAlpha["determinant of \
{{0,1/v,-k_{12}/v^2},{k_{12},k_{01},0},{1,1,0}}", 
 PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution"}]

WolframAlpha["determinant of {{0,1/v,0},{k_{12},k_{01},0},{1,1,1}}", 
 PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: If you apply  Laplace-rule you have to multiply the 3x3-determinants  with the right element of the first column (and alternating sign) before summation

Comment: Hello @UlrichNeumann I did it. The result $-k_{12}/v$ takes into account the signs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Det[{{0, 1/v, 0, -k12/v^2}, 
     {0, 0, 0, -1/v^2}, 
     {k12, k01, 0, 0}, 
     {1, 1, 1, 0}}]
(* k12/v^3*)
```

Laplace

```
(* first two elements of 1st column==0 *) 
k12* Det[{{ 1/v, 0, -k12/v^2}, {0, 0, -1/v^2}, { 1, 1, 0}}] - 
1*Det[{{ 1/v, 0, -k12/v^2}, { 0, 0, -1/v^2}, { k01, 0, 0} }]     
(* k12/v^3*)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much @UlrichNeumann

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly wasteful, but you can use `Minors[]` to extract the submatrices needed for cofactor expansion:

```
mat = {{0, 1/v, 0, -k12/v^2}, {0, 0, 0, -1/v^2}, {k12, k01, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0}};
submats = Minors[mat, 3, Identity][[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, -1]];
```

From there, here's a manual cofactor expansion evaluation:

```
(mat[[All, 1]] PadRight[{}, Length[mat], {1, -1}]).Map[Det, submats]
   k12/v^3
```

Extracting other rows and columns of the result of `Minors[]` allows you to perform cofactor expansion over other rows or columns; you will just need to reverse things accordingly, as I have done.

Comment: good solution. Thank you very much.